# Partial Rendering of Form fields with ajax valueChange event in jsf

Tags: ajax, jsf

```
<h:form id="newStudentForm">
    <h:outputLabel value="Student" for="studentId" />
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{myBean.studentId}" id="studentId">
        <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.studentList}" var="student"
                       itemLabel="#{student.name}" itemValue="#{student.id}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <h:outputLabel value="Address" for="addressId" />
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{myBean.addressId}" id="addressId">
        <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.addressList}" var="address"
                       itemLabel="#{address.name}" itemValue="#{address.id}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <h:outputLabel value="Address" for="addressId" />
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{myBean.subjectId}" id="subjectId">
        <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.subjectList}" var="subject"
                       itemLabel="#{subject.name}" itemValue="#{subject.id}" />

        <a4j:ajax event="valueChange"
                  render="newStudentForm" 
                  listener="#{myBean.checkSubject}"
                  execute="@this"/>  
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <h:outputLabel value="Price" for="priceId" rendered="#{myBean.checkSubject}" />
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{myBean.priceId}" id="priceId"
                     rendered="#{myBean.checkSubject}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.priceList}" var="price"
                       itemLabel="#{price.name}" itemValue="#{price.id}"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

I am trying to make a field dynamic i.e field Price, when i am selecting a value from subject, the price field is dependent on that value. Everything is working fine in this code except that when i am rendering the form, the values that i enter in other fields(like address) before selecting subject is being overridden by the initial values. So how should i refactor this ajax event call so that the values do not get overridden.
The checkSubject function is returning true or false based on subject selected.

Comment: can you also show the code of your bean? is it `@RequestScoped`?

Comment: 1: Why are you using `a4j:ajax` in PrimeFaces and not `p:ajax`? 2: [mcve]

Comment: No, it is not requestScoped, it is viewScoped.

Comment: But maybe the wrong viewscoped.... [mcve] including imports of scopes please

Comment: import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped  , @ViewScoped - This is the annotation of the java file. Do i need to edit this xhtml or bean level change is required?

Comment: i think you need a `p:ajax` with `change` event. see [pf's showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/event.xhtml)